# Firestore Permission denied in production Electron app but requests go through in development

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, electron, electron-builder

I have added multiple rules to my Firestore database. When I test the app in development mode, everything works as it should but for some reason when I build and run the app for production all my requests are denied with "Missing or insufficient permissions."

I cannot allow anyone to read, and the documents. The rules are vital and I am not sure that they are the problem anyway. I have used the Firestore simulator to test calls, as well as the emulator.

I am building with the command:

```sh
electron-builder build --win --x64
```

The rules

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 function owns(id) {
   return request.auth.uid == id;
 }
 match /{userId}/{document=**} {
   allow read, write: if owns(userId);
 }
}
```

```js
load(collectionName) {
  const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  let collection = uid && 
   firebase.firestore().collection(uid).doc("data").collection(collectionName);
  }

  return collection.get();
}
```

Basically the top level of the database is the user ids, and a user can access collection within their top-level collection.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the specific rules and client code that aren't working the way you expect.  We should be able to reproduce the issue from what you provide in the question

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added the details.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to an issue in [firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk)

The corresponding issue is here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1491